# Elasticsearch Java High-Level REST Client establish a bunch of TCP connection and doesn't close them after indexing data

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a periodic job that has been run every second (this is configurable).

In this job, I first create a connection to Elasticsearch server:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                    RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(address, port, "http")));
```

Then I check for the existence of a special index called `test`. If it doesn't exist, I create it first.

```
GetIndexRequest indexRequest = new GetIndexRequest();
indexRequest.indices("test");
boolean testIndexIsExists = false;
try {           
     testIndexIsExists = client.indices().exists(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT); 
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    logger.error("Can't check the existence of test index in Elasticsearch!");  
}
if(testIndexIsExists) {
     // bulk request...
} else {
    CreateIndexRequest testIndex = new CreateIndexRequest("test");
    try {   
        testIndex.mapping("doc", mappingConfiguration);
        client.indices().create(testIndex, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        // bulk request...  
    } catch (IOException ioe) { 
        logger.error("Can't create test index in Elasticsearch");
    }   
}
```

And after doing a bulk request that has near 2000 document, I close the Elasticsearch client connection:

```
client.close();
```

Java High Level REST Client version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My problem is a bunch of TCP connection that has been established and don't be closed. These TCP connections occupy all operating system TCP connections over time.

On the other hand, I'm a bit confused. Should `RestHighLevelClient` instance be a singleton object for the entire application or I must create a new instance in every job running cycle and close the instance after doing that job?

Comment: Are you using more than one client instance at a time in your application? Because you should be using only one and use that one the whole time. Then `close` when your app exits. It should handle everything else on it's own.

Comment: What is the exact version of elastic and client you are using?

Comment: Elasticsearch: 6.6.1, Java High Level REST Client: 6.4.0

Comment: Why not keep the client instance around instead of creating new every time?

Comment: Do the connections clear up after the application is terminated?

Comment: yes, all connections are closed.

Comment: That makes me think either ES client or Apache client isn't correctly releasing the connection. Perhaps you could try a later version of the ES client to see if it's improved. But in general the client can and should be used as a singleton.

Answer (score 12):

The high level client is already maintaining a connection pool for you, so I would use it as a singleton. Constantly creating and closing connection pools is expensive, and the client and underlying HTTP connection pool are thread safe. Also, calling `close()` on the client just delegates to the Apache HTTP client `shutdown()` method, so you're at the mercy of how they handle cleanup and releasing resources.

If you're using Spring or some other DI framework, it's easy to create a singleton instance of the client that can be injected as needed. And you can add the call to `client.close()` as part of the bean shutdown/destroy lifecycle phase.

Quick example using Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(RestHighLevelClient.class)
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.address}")
    String address;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    int port;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient() {
        return new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(address, port, "http")));
    }
}
```

*Note: In this case Spring will automatically detect that the bean has a `close` method and call it for you when the bean is destroyed. Other frameworks may require you to specify how shutdown should be handled.*

Comment: Nice, but Sonar is not able to detect this fix, so you must provide `// NOSONAR` hint

Answer (score 0):

`RestHighLevelClient` should generally be singleton, unless you have a good reason. For example if your job is running every hour and not a minute it might make sense to create new instance and close it after the job.

If you are sure you are calling the `close()` in all cases (e.g. you haven't missed any exceptions) then my next guess is bug in the elastic client.

It look like they are forgetting to consume the response in the exists call:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v6.4.0/client/rest-high-level/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.java#L1419

Are you able to test without the `exists` call?